YTM and Accrual
Can you please clarify if the YTM (yield to maturity) of a bond is the implied yield using the clean price or the dirty price? Does YTM incorporates interest accrual ?
If so, let's assume my bond pays semi annual coupons and the currently accrual period is 3 months
for example  semi annual coupon = $3 that will be paid in 3 months, which one should I use:
dirty price = $3/(1+YTM)^1/4  + ...
or
clean price = $1.5/(1+YTM)^1/4  + ...

A yield is the internal rate of return of a series of cash flows: you pay "proceeds" to buy the the bond and subsequently receive coupons and principal repayments.
Coupon-paying bonds have positive accrued on most settlement dates, except at the start of a coupon period.
Most bonds in most markets are quoted "clean", meaning that to calculate the proceeds, you indeed need to add to the quoted price the amount accrued until the settlement date.
Calculating a yield using only a clean price, excluding the accrued, would be less meaningful.
But there are a few exceptions that you should keep in mind:
Bonds that are distressed, but not yet defaulted, are usually quoted dirty. Don't add the accrued. (And don't calculate yields of defaulted bonds.)
Preferred equities are a lot like perpetual bonds, but are quoted dirty.
In a few emerging markets, such as Brazil, bonds that are not distressed are also quoted dirty. Etc.

so you would use clean price + Accrual  = clean price + interest from previous cpn date to next settlement date (t+2) right?

I believe thee days T+1 may be more common than T+2. https://www.investor.gov/introduction-investing/general-resources/news-alerts/alerts-bulletins/investor-bulletins/new-t1-settlement-cycle-what-investors-need-know-investor-bulletin
